# Does a Push Notification Service (Apple/Google) have to be mentioned in an DPA. Do i need a DPA with the Service Providers?

Tags: gdpr, european-union, data-protection

We are a Software Company that provides a Software (an IOS and Android Application) to our Customers. That Customer itself would be treated as an Data Controller and thus we are the Data Processor, therefore we need a DPA (Data Processing Agreement) with our Customers. In this DPA i need to specify which Data we process and which other Data Processers we use (maybe called "Subprocessors", or "Subcompanys"). Our App uses a Backend that is not hosted inhouse, therefore we have an DPA with our Hoster and mention them in our DPA with our Customers. Now we face the "Problem" that Push Tokens are treated as an Identifier (as they shoud), and in our case the Push Messeges themselves contain personal Information. This Data (even just the Push Token) is of course shared with Apple and Google, because our App couldn't otherwise have Push Notifications. Do i need to specify Apple/Google as "Subprocessors" in my DPA? As for Google i know it is very hard to get an DPA with them, especially as a very small Start-Up. When using the Push-Services from them i share user data with them and i need an DPA with them right? But how come this Question never rose up? What am i missing?

Comment: When sending a physical letter, would you need a DPA with the postal services? Are Google/Apple in a similar position here as the postal services for a physical letter?